# Dynamic form for hstore

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Is there a straightforward way to create a dynamic **form/view** for an hstore attribute?

I've used Cocoon to handle nested attributes in my views, but apparently can't do the same thing with hstore, using Cocoon.

i need something to handle the views.

basically every time the user needs a new key/value, hit add button and a new key/value field pops to enter and save.

ive found [this](https://github.com/heroku/hstore_example/blob/master/app/views/products/_form.html.erb), but looks outdated.

Is there any good example?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript library to do the front end?  Or are you looking for ruby code to handle the controller logic?

Comment: Yes, to do the frontend.